# Area of a field given in parametric form

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm given two functions of $t$:

$$
x=t^2-1, y=t^3-t
$$

After I compare $y$ to $0$, I get that the integration bounds are $-1\leq t\leq1$ The derivative of $x$ is $x'=2t$. I write the integral as:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} |2t\,(t^3-t)|dt = \int_{-1}^{1} |2t^4-2t^2|dt
$$

Now, since the integrated function is always greater than, or equal to zero, I skip the absolute value:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} 2t^4dt - \int_{-1}^{1}2t^2dt = \frac{2}{5}t^5-\frac{2}{3}t^3
$$

Now when I put numbers as t, the result I get is $-\frac{8}{15}$ which is an obvious nonsense. Using some online integral calculators, I get $\frac{8}{15}$, but despite my best efforst, I'm unable to get to that result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $t < 1$ then $t^4 < t^2$. Small minus big is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake that you're making is skipping the absolute value completely.

For $t<1$, $t^4<t^2$, meaning that $t^4-t^2<0$.

This is how the integral should actually be split up.
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}|2t^4-2t^2|dt=\int_{-1}^{0}-2t^4+2t^2dt+\int_{0}^{1}-2t^4+2t^2dt=(-\frac{2}{5}t^5+\frac{2}{3}t^3)\Biggr|_{-1}^{0}+(-\frac{2}{5}t^5+\frac{2}{3}t^3)\Biggr|_{0}^{1}=-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{8}{15}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

The assumption that $ 0 \leq 2t^4 - 2t^2$ is false. This is because for $t < 1$ then $t^4 < t^2$ and so $t^4-t^2 < 0$.